# ImageView in android not filling whole page using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am facing problem while loading an Image in ViewPager. The image gets loaded with 5px gap at right and left side. Here is my code:

```
 @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(PoemActivity.mPoems[position]);
        container.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }
```

Here is my xml file as asked by Hari.

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Without seeing any code, i do nothing. But if you want to solve your problem, then use android layout margin left and right property's value having -5px.

Comment: @RohitSingh Thanks. I am doing that programmatically. How to do that?

Comment: show ur xml layout which contains the viewpager

Comment: hey @HariKrishnan See I have updated the xml.

Comment: @TechBee Can you tell me where you use your code? Means it is adapter's  code. If yes, then paste your xml code here.

Comment: yes @RohitSingh this is adapter code.

Comment: @TechBee. May be your parent layout (relative layout) contain automatic generated margin. Also give us that full code.

Comment: this isn't enough. plz provide tha whole xml layout code